# How to edit the “create new article” section of MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

How can I edit the edit section of MediaWiki? I want to change the instructions and provide options for preloads on the “create new article” page.

Comment: Can you add an URL or screenshot of the “create new article” section of MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the MediaWiki:Noarticletext page.